# RenderClass with Multithread-Support, push functioncalls to vector for invoking on another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pointer-to-member, member-functions

I'm trying to make a RenderClass where 1 function gets called from a Thread, which calculates everything and pushes the function calls to a vector while the other Thread calls a function of RenderClass which then calls every function that got pushed on the vector, is this even possible? also my code doesn't give me intellisense errors in vs just some weird C3867 error that doesn't make sense in my opinion when trying to compile.

I already tried playing around with the template function
like removing the RenderClass::*function to

```cpp
template<typename Function, typename ...ARGS>
    void QueueRenderFunction(Function *function, ARGS... args)
```

but can't get it to work.

here the whole testprogram I tested this on...

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

class Vector3 {
    float x, y, z;
};

class RenderClass
{
public:
    template<typename Function, typename ...ARGS>
    void QueueRenderFunction(Function RenderClass::*function, ARGS... args)
    {
        _RenderList.push_back(std::forward<Function>(function, args...));
    }
    void CallRenderFunctions()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(renderlist_mtx);
        for (auto&& Function : RenderList)
            Function();
    }

    //just as examplecode
    void DRAWCIRCLE(Vector3 Position, float Range) {
        std::cout << Range << std::endl;
    }
    void DRAWSTRING(Vector3 Position, std::string String) {
        std::cout << String << std::endl;
    }

    void QueueDrawings() {
        //begin new Renderlist
        _RenderList.clear();
        //some drawing calcs

        //some Position
        Vector3 Position;
        QueueRenderFunction(DRAWCIRCLE, Position, 100.f);
        QueueRenderFunction(DRAWSTRING, Position,"Name");

        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> l(renderlist_mtx);
        RenderList = _RenderList;
    }

private:
    std::recursive_mutex renderlist_mtx;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> RenderList;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> _RenderList;
};

RenderClass* Renderer = new RenderClass();
void Render() {
    while (true)
    {
        Renderer->CallRenderFunctions();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }

}

int main() {
    std::thread RenderThread(Render);
    while (true)
    {
        Renderer->QueueDrawings();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

like said I get for example this error:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C3867    'RenderClass::DRAWCIRCLE': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

and trying to &DRAWCIRCLE just then gives me

> Error  C2276    '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

that's what makes me say it doesn't make sense in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have a `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`, which is fine, but you need to add some augments. std::bind is your friend.

This code should do the trick.

```
template<typename Function, typename ...ARGS>
void QueueRenderFunction(Function function, ARGS... args)
{
    _RenderList.push_back(std::bind(function, args...));
}
```

You probably also want to define the function you put into the render list as free from functions and pass what would have been this as argument.

As a side note, you probably want to use `RenderList.swap(_RenderList);` to reduce copying.

Comment: hey @rioki thanks for the helpful answer , it seems to work now at least, when im putting the functions outside of the class , but i still cant pass it inside the class as memberfunction , do u have an idea how i could fix this ?

Comment: You may want to look into std::mem_fun which can be used to capture member functions. The downside is that you need to pass (or bind) the this pointer. Alternatively sigc::mem_fun does the this binding automatically: https://github.com/libsigcplusplus/libsigcplusplus/blob/master/sigc%2B%2B/functors/mem_fun.h You could copy their scheme.